# Android SoftKeyBoard - rename the Enter Key

Tags: android, xml, android-softkeyboard, enter

i have several EditText in my App. If you hit the Enter Key you can tab to the next EditText without a problem but i would like to change the Enter Key so that this button doesn't shows the Enter Simbol but instead it shows "Next" or "Done". i tried many things but without any results. Here is the XML code for my EditText:

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_nt_name"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext|flagNoEnterAction"
            android:imeActionLabel="Next"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:inputType="textShortMessage"
/>
```

Comment: i found it out...
instead of 

    android:imeOptions="actionNext|flagNoEnterAction"

i only needed:

    android:imeOptions="actionNext"

Answer (score 0):

it is the case that some soft keyboards actually change the default text on the enter key by design, so it may not be your fault that it's not showing what you want it to show. the functionality should be the what you programmed it to do, though.

i recommend you switch to the default keyboard (long press on any edit text, then select input method) to verify that it's showing the correct text, and don't care about the what the other soft keyboards look like .

if your phone didn't come with the default soft keyboard, the Android emulator is your best friend.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your EditText,

```
 android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```